# No colors in weechat, tig, htop, ranger, etc

Tags: macos, terminal, fish, ncurses

I noticed that on my Mac I don't have any colors in e.g., `tig`, `weechat`, `htop` or `ranger`. On my linux I do. It happens in all terminal apps I have (alacritty, iterm and Terminal.app), in `zsh`, `fish` and `bash`.

I'm at a loss how to debug this. My fish syntax highlighting works, `ls` has colors, `nvim` has colors, `git diff` has colors. It appears to happen only in such interactive CLI apps which, I assume, use ncurses

Comment: What is `$TERM` set to? Does `type htop` give you the expected path to that command?

Comment: `$TERM` is `screen-256color` in `tmux` and `xterm-256color` outside of `tmux`. `type htop` gives me `usr/local/bin/htop` as is expected since I installed it through `homebrew`.

Comment: Works for me on macOS using iTerm and fish as well as the other bits you mentioned. Too, while I've seen people have problems with colored output. Usually due to the wrong `TERM` or a wrapper around the command that inhibits colored ouput; e.g., that ends up running `htop --no-color`. I've never seen a case like yours that affects only some commands. There isn't anything about macOS which would account for the problem.

Comment: What exact version of macOS?

Comment: `10.14.3` macOS Mojave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a `.terminfo` folder in my home folder, with data from [invisible-island.net](http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/terminfo.src.gz). Removing it brought back colors in the above mentioned commands.
I then had to fix italics in `tmux` but that's another story (I installed the linked terminfo precisely in my efforts to fix italics in `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

For me the cause of the problem was also a custom `.terminfo`. I wanted to keep the `.terminfo` (to get italics in tmux) so I for me the best solution is

```
alias tig='TERM=xterm-256color tig'
```

Using this alias the colors return to `tig`.